# CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE in ODB11G

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a table:

```
CUST_ID;Bon;Netturnover

   1;2;440   
   1;1;500   
   2;3;9000   
   3;1;2500
```

I created a procedure but it does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_Proc
(P_ID OUT NUMBER, F1 IN NUMBER, M1 IN NUMBER) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT CUST_ID INTO P_ID FROM test WHERE CUST_ID = P_ID
GROUP BY CUST_ID
HAVING SUM(Bon)< F1 AND SUM(Netturnover) > M1;
END TEST_Proc;

EXECUTE TEST_Proc (3,450);
```

Error message:

> - ORA-01403: no data
> - ORA-06512: the "SYSTEM.TEST_PROC", the place at # 4
> - ORA-06512: the , the place at # 9

What is the problem?

Basically, I’d like to get information like this:

```
SELECT CUST_ID FROM test 
GROUP BY CUST_ID
HAVING SUM(Bon)< 3 AND SUM(Netturnover) > 450;
```

... just automatically with a procedure.

Comment: Firstly, you are only passing two parameters `(3,450)` into a procedure that requires three `(P_ID OUT NUMBER, F1 IN NUMBER, M1 IN NUMBER)`, so you will get _PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROC'_.

Comment: `P_ID` has to be `IN OUT` because you are passing it as a paramater to your procedure.

Comment: Secondly, `P_ID` is an OUT parameter which requires a variable to receive the updated value. It can't update the literal `3`.

Comment: Thirdly, if there are no rows in the table matching your query it will give a `ORA-01403: no_data_found` exception.

Comment: Fourthly, it doesn't make sense to update `p_id` because you already know what it is, unless there is no matching value in which case it will fail anyway. What is it meant to do?

Comment: Thanks for your effort to solve my problem. First I thought the OUT parameter does not have to be given, so those were the parameters "F1" and "M1". Basically I do not want to use CUST_ID as a variable if it is not necessary. What I would like to get from this procedure is a filtered list of the CUST_ID, in this case the result is the Cust_ID: 3.  I would like to apply this procedure at a bigger dataset.

Comment: So, then, why do you have the condition `CUST_ID = P_ID` in the join? You should remove it. Then: it is possible that the query will return more than one CUST_ID that satisfies all the (other) conditions. Don't you need to return all of them? And what should be returned when no customer satisfies all the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling with only two values, but you need three:

```
declare
    p_id number;
begin
    p_id := 3;
    EXECUTE TEST_Proc (pid, 450, ??);
end;
```

Then, your query is really strange, because you are passing back the value passed in.  Okay, call it an `IN OUT` parameter.  More importantly, the subquery may return *no* rows, and you don't handle that.

You could do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_Proc (
    in_out_P_ID IN OUT NUMBER,
    in_F1 IN NUMBER,
    in_M1 IN NUMBER
) AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(Bon)< in_F1 AND SUM(Netturnover) > in_M1
                 THEN CUST_ID
            END) INTO P_ID
    FROM test
    WHERE CUST_ID = in_out_P_ID
END TEST_Proc;
```

Note that the parameter names are prefixed, to help avoid collisions with column names.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed a bit the script and it works, but can I apply this procedure without insering any CUST_ID parameter?            CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_Proc (
    P_ID IN OUT NUMBER,
    F1 IN NUMBER,
    M1 IN NUMBER
) AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(Bon)< F1 AND SUM(Netturnover) > M1
                 THEN CUST_ID
            END) as custid INTO P_ID
    FROM test
    WHERE CUST_ID = P_ID
    GROUP BY CUST_ID;
END TEST_Proc;